# Цикл в многомерном массиве

Tags: php, html, mysql, массивы

Здравствуйте,есть массив вида:

```
 Array
    (
        [names] => Array
            (
                [0] => Вова
                [1] => Олег
            )

        [numbers] => Array
            (
                [0] => +79111234567
                [1] => 354-23-44
            )

    )
```

Необходимо сделать запрос в mysql вида `INSERT INTO test VALUES(Вова,+79111234567))`
Проблема в том, что нужно делать это с помощью цикла и для Вовы и для Олега что бы ключ в массиве numbers соответствовал ключу из массива names. Каким образом это можно реализовать с помощью php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> что бы ключ в массиве numbers соответствовал ключу из массива names.

Именно так и делать - брать ключ из первого массива и использовать во втором.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO test VALUES(?,?)");
foreach($array['names'] as $key => $name)
{
    $number = $array['numbers'][$key];
    $stmt->execute([$name, $number]);
}
```

Comment: Респект, твоё решение затащило.